# Angular dart radio buttons not binding to model

Tags: html, radio-button, dart, angular-dart

I have an Angular Dart component with the following html:

EDIT: For some reason some of my html did not copy properly. outside of the label tag I have:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
```

`

```
    <label ng-repeat="item in items" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" ng-show="isItemVisible(item)">

        <input type="radio" name="options" value="{{item}}" ng-model="selected">{{item}}
            <span class="badge pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></span>

    </label>
</div>`
```

However, this never updates the model. I have also tried using onclick, ng-click, and ng-change with the same result- the functions never get called. Is there some directive that I'm using incorrectly?

Comment: Hey you might consider making selected a part of hte item object. like ng-model="item.selected" and adding item.text for the text.

Comment: Yeah, same problem for dropdowns... the model has not been updated when the callback is executed... setTimeout 0 / wrap the callback in a future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Future in your `ng-click` so it will allow your model to get updated.

```
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="{{item}}" 
         ng-model="selected" ng-click="radioButtonClicked();">{{item}}</input>

   //Component Code:
   void radioButtonClicked(){
            new Future((){
                //Use your selected model here.
            });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

$parent should do the trick. Here is working example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <label for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}:</label>
    <input id="{{item.name}}" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.$parent.selected" ng-value="item.value" />
  </div>

  <strong>Selected value:</strong> {{$parent.selected}} <br/>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [{
  name:'Item1',
  value: 'value1'
}, {
  name:'Item2',
  value: 'value2'
}, {
  name:'Item3',
  value: 'value3'
}];

$scope.selected = null;
```

Comment: This may not be applicable to my problem as I am using AngularDart. My controller is a Dart Component.